# Possible to create thumbnails of MS Office files?

Tags: ms-office, thumbnails, preview

Have anybody ever tried to create thumbnails/previews of MS Office files? I do not mean extract saved preview images inside the file, but actually create them. Would this even be doable?

Could one print to an image/pdf directly in code?

Comment: also, are you talking about some kind of screenshot per page, worksheet, slide, etc.? or are you talking about replacing the actual thumbnail view of an Office file (that is viewed in Windows Explorer) with your own image?

Comment: No particular office version, any version really. And the documents are stored in a database and servered via a web UI, I'd like to provide thumbnails in the web UI.

Comment: @noocyte: so you'd like a way to extra the existing thumbnail image from the Office file? If so, it's pretty easy for Office 2007 files. Please confirm if that' what you want and I'll show you how.

Comment: No, not extract the thumbnail. Create a thumbnail based on the actual document. Basically we have a bunch of office/pdf/img files stored in a database and we need to open the files, snapshot the first page and then store that snapshot as a JPG/PNG into the database again.

Comment: Office 2007 automatically creates this "snapshot of the first page" based on the actual document for it's files that can easily be extracted. For what you want to do manually (open, screen print first page, put capture back in DB), not sure how to do that.

Comment: noocyte, Can you post the code you used to get this done?  I am interested in the exact same thing.

Comment: I have not yet done this... But will be using a PDF library to do it, from Docscorp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general VB/C# application, add the MSword/MSexcel component and call the component to open the file you want. Then call one of the print functions with the parameters corresponding to first page etc.

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380) shows how to open a .xls from C#